# Dose normalization help to get better correlation?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, normalization, correlation

I have a set of numeric features and I would like to use then to predict the price of product. I didn't get any meaningful correlation between the features and the price. Can I improve the correlation by normalizing the features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just testing corr(x_i, y), where y is price, and x_i is i'th feature, then no, you cannot improve this value by normalization, as correlation is affine transformations invariant, meaning that for any choice of a, b, c, d > 0

```
corr(a + bx_i, c + dy) = corr(x_i, y)
```